# Can I determine if an Office document has been opened by external automation code?

Tags: .net, automation, ms-office, vsto

I have some code in an Office VSTO addin (implemented for Word, Excel 2003 & 2007 in VB.NET) that is causing problems for some external automation code.

Is there a way I can determine whether an Office document has been opened by automation code, versus opened by a user? Some difference in the Application or Document objects, or an event I can handle that only fires in one or the other circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so when an Office application is opened through the Office Object Model, the command line uses the `/automation` switch (eg. `Winword.exe /automation`).

So I'm just checking for this in the startup of my addin and setting a global Boolean:

```
If (Environment.CommandLine.IndexOf("/automation", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) Then mbOpenedByAutomation = True
```

I've got to do some testing to make sure there aren't any other situations which might use that switch, but I think this will do the trick.

Comment: I'd check that that will still apply if word is already loaded and the user opens another document via the object model. Generally, it won't start another instance of word, so that trick might not work in all situations.

Comment: Automation code will create a new instance, that's actually the cause of one of our problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally speaking, automation will open documents NON VISIBLE, so you should be able to test the visibility of the document during the documentOpen event. It might not be perfect, but as far as I know, there's no way for a user to manually open a document invisibly, so it should work.

OTOH, some automation intentionally opens documents visibly (so the user can edit them), so that might not be a 100% solution.

Comment: Someone on my team suggested this but as you said, it's not reliable and the specific automation code I'm having trouble with actually has the UI visible.